# Convert a Map[Int, Array[(Int, Int)]] to Map[Int, Map[Int, Int]] in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a data structure like this:

```
Map(
  0 -> Array((1,1), (2,1)),
  1 -> Array((2,1), (3,1), (0,1)),
  2 -> Array((4,1), (0,1), (1,1)),
  3 -> Array((1,1)),
  4 -> Array((5,1), (2,1)),
  5 -> Array((4,1))
)
```

and the result I need should look like this:

```
Map(
  0 -> Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 1),
  1 -> Map(2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 0 -> 1),
  2 -> Map(4 -> 1, 0 -> 1, 1 -> 1),
  3 -> Map(1 -> 1),
  4 -> Map(5 -> 1, 2 -> 1),
  5 -> Map(4 -> 1)
)
```

Comment: What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: You could get the output you want by writing a program in Scala which does what you want. If you encounter a problem with this program you have written, you carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, and libraries you are using, single-step through the code in a debugger, write tests, trace the execution with pen&paper, and if you still can't figure out the problem … wait a week and then start with fresh eyes and a fresh mind. Then, and only then, if you still have problems, you can read up on how to construct a [mcve] and write a narrow, specific, focused question on [so].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really simple:     `yourMap.mapValues(_.toMap)`

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

Map(
  0 -> Array((1,1), (2,1)),
  1 -> Array((2,1), (3,1), (0,1)),
  2 -> Array((4,1), (0,1), (1,1)),
  3 -> Array((1,1)),
  4 -> Array((5,1), (2,1)),
  5 -> Array((4,1))
)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Array[(Int, Int)]] = Map(0 -> Array((1,1), (2,1)), 5 -> Array((4,1)), 1 -> Array((2,1), (3,1), (0,1)), 2 -> Array((4,1), (0,1), (1,1)), 3 -> Array((1,1)), 4 -> Array((5,1), (2,1)))

scala> res0.mapValues(_.toMap)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]] = Map(0 -> Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 1), 5 -> Map(4 -> 1), 1 -> Map(2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 0 -> 1), 2 -> Map(4 -> 1, 0 -> 1, 1 -> 1), 3 -> Map(1 -> 1), 4 -> Map(5 -> 1, 2 -> 1))
```